# How to execute REPLACE query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to execute query in SQL Server using terminal.

Query

```
REPLACE INTO [wine].[Spirits] (skuId, name, packageDescription, packageValue, price) 
VALUES ('1', '1a', '2b', 'd', '12.00')
```

Error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server localhost, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

Additional info: insert query is working properly

```
INSERT INTO [wine].[Spirits] (skuId, name, packageDescription, packageValue, price) 
VALUES ('1', 'a', 'b', 'd', '12.00')
```

Can anyone point out what's I'm doing wrong here?

I know this sounds like very basic question in SQL Server, but sorry I'm new to this language.

I'm not sure whether `REPLACE` is available in SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: `REPLACE` is a function, not an operator; what are you expecting it to do here?

Comment: If the skuId exists, I want the row to updated, otherwise insert as new row. that's what REPLACE does in MySQL, MariaDB. I don't know whether it's something possible to do in MSSQL.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: You want a `MERGE` or "Upsert".

Comment: seems REPLACE INTO is not a feature in MSSQL according to that answers. I will go with if condition check method. anyway thanks for the help.